# Importing csv using Datagrip (table with identity column)

Tags: datagrip

How to import CSV file into SQL Server table with identity column using DataGrip.

More precisely, how to exclude the identity column during the import or force importing the identity column?

Comment: There is no possibility like this, but we plan to have it in 2017.1 version, so please watch'n'vote this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-3141

Answer (score 1):

Assume, you've got a table

```sql
create table test_identity_insert(
   x bigint primary key identity(1,1), 
  y int );
go
```

You need to [change data mappings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/import-file-name-format-dialog.html#table-name-structure-and-data-mappings)

[image: Data Mapping]

Answer (score -1):

From the 'Import: "file_Name.csv" Format' window, on the Columns tab, click the trash can icon with the Identity column highlighted. (See [screencap here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84Yiu.png), I don't currently have the reputation allowed to insert images.)

Also, see the bottom of the 'Import:  Format Dialog' help page in DataGrip, or the web help [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/2016.3/import-file-name-format-dialog.html).